# Как дополнить запись в базе данных

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

У меня проект mvc, использую entity framework для общения с базой данных. Например, мне нужно записать в колонку pictures несколько значений через разделитель. Для этого я пишу:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(...))
{
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.pictures, new { size = 87 })<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.pictures, new { size = 87 })<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.pictures, new { size = 87 })<br />
...
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
}
```

Но, конечно же, от каждого textbox'a в pictures текст не добавляется, а просто записывается то, что было введено в последнем textbox'e.

Как мне написать, чтобы в pictures текст добавлялся, а не перезаписывался при каждом повторном изменении Model.pictures, плюс к тому же, чтобы между ними был разделитель, например, запятая. Чтобы в базе данных получилось что-то вроде: "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg".

Comment: даже не знаю что и делать. Можно конечно сделать textarea и добавлять ссылки на картинки через запятую вручную. но это будет выглядит не красиво. Это скорее применимо к тегам. К тому же я хотел написать на jquery кнопочку которая добавляет textbox'ы при каждом нажатии, куда можно будет разместить еще одни ссылки, если тех картинок будет не достаточно. Вот вот это бы выглядело красиво.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось: написал на javascript'e так, чтобы все, что было введено в `textbox'ах`, размещалось в невидимом текстовом поле, которое и будет отправляться как `pictures`.

Answer (score 0):

Записывайте в базу `CurrentPictureText += PictureName + ","`. Если используете сгенерированный  `entity framework`'ом метод  то сделайте поверх него метод, который и будет выполнять нужное действие над базой, в данном случае дописывать текст.

Comment: к сожалению, я ничего не понял. Я отправляю запрос на контроллер, который принимает 1 аргумент - новую модель(сформированную с помощью этих textbox'оф), которая, в последствии, заменяется на старую. А как мне сделать так чтобы post запрос отправлял все эти значения pictures как одно значение. чтобы до отправки, до post запроса, они уже были объединены?

Answer (score 0):

Если отправить форму методом get, то на сервере в параметре pictures все значения будут через запятую.

Comment: о, интересно, я не знал